# Nuget renaming web.config to web.config.transform

Tags: c#, nuget

When I pack my `.csproj` into a `.nupkg` it renames the `Web.config` to `Web.config.transform`. I have written a script to undo this after I install/deploy the Nuget package, but I am wondering if there is a way to prevent Nuget from renaming my web.config on a pack or if it is an inevitable part of the design of a Nuget pack.

I am running `NuGet.exe` `v3.4.4` with `-IncludeReferencedProjects` as a command line parameter and with my Configuration set to Release.

My install cleanup if anyone is interested in the hacky way to fix this:

```
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path .\bin
xcopy .\lib\net45 .\bin /y /s
xcopy .\content .\  /y /s
Move-Item Web.config.transform Web.config -Force
```

Comment: Are you sure that you really _want_ to overwrite a consuming project's web.config with your own? What about their application settings? NuGet packages should apply tranforms instead to ensure your new settings are added / removed on install / uninstall. https://docs.nuget.org/create/configuration-file-and-source-code-transformations

Comment: Yes I am sure, I want to configure the web config from my hot drop on deployment via my octopus deploy setup.

Comment: my nuget files won't know which environment to apply transforms too.. unless i am doing the entire process wrong. should i be doing a single nuget package for an entire environment? so hosting a dozen or so packages for all the different evironments

Comment: It's by design, you definitely don't want to overwrite the web.config file when someone adds your package. Web.config is used by many packages and has all sorts of things in it the user may have already configured, hence why you get a transform file that applies transformations to the web.config instead.

There is likely a better approach to what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Well I guess my question is moot then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you just want to deploy the Asp.net application via Octopus, am I right? Although Octopus suggest to use NuGet package for deployment, you can't treat the NuGet as it's designed for packaging libraries to be used in Visual Studio.

> NuGet was designed for packaging libraries to be used in Visual Studio, which is a different usage scenario than that of deploying applications. When creating a library NuGet package, for example, NuGet encourages you to put binaries in a lib folder, and content files in the content folder. But for Octopus Deploy, this convention doesn't make sense - your ASP.NET application will expect binaries to be in a bin folder for example. Instead, just ignore the NuGet package structure conventions, and simply structure your package exactly like you want it to appear when extracted on disk.

Read [here](http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/display/OD/NuGet+packages) for details.

As suggested, you should structure your own Nuspec file.

Comment: Thank you, following this advice I seem to be on the right track.